# How to use a parameter in a script in other scripts

Tags: r

I want to one parameter in one R script in another R script. For example in the first file for reading data:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("adress")
dat <-readWorksheet(wb, sheet=getSheets(wb)[1], startRow=strow, endRow=endrow, startCol=spalte, endCol=spalte,header=FALSE)
datalist<-dat[,1]
while(n<=length(datalist))
{
  m<-strsplit(datalist[n],split=",")
  m<-sapply(m,as.numeric)
  m<-c(m)

  input<-m
  # here I want to set input to another file
  run1 <- parse("~/second.R")

  n<-n+30
}
```

In the `second.R` I have a parameter which name is `input`

but this code doesnt run `second.R`. What should I do to solve this problem?

**Update**

the second.R is:

```
wbdb <- loadWorkbook("C:\\Adress\\Muster.xls")
datdb <-readWorksheet(wbdb, sheet=getSheets(wb)[1], startRow=1, endRow=35, startCol=1, endCol=2,header=FALSE)
datalistdb<-datdb[,1]

ke<-length(input)
i<-1
near<-1000
position<-0
while(i < 35)
{ 
  m<-strsplit(datalistdb[i],split=",")
  m<-sapply(m,as.numeric)
  m<-c(m)
  alignment<-dtw(input,m)


  if(alignment$distance < near)
  {
    near<-alignment$distance
    position<-i
  }
  i<-i+1
}
position
datdb[position,2]
```

Comment: What is the **exact** content of `second.R`? Do you want to run `second.R` with the `input` variable set to `m` and then get the result to `run1`?

Comment: Isn't this the sort of thing god created functions for?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I want to test it in this way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
run1 <- source("~/second.R")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, now I am seeing something as an output, but not what I am expecting: $value
`[1] 33

$visible
[1] TRUE`

Comment: check your code, I did't get what you're trying do. Also, you can always open other question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`eval`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html) with `second.R`:

```
run1 <- eval(parse("~/second.R"))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work. I want to run second.R an Have a resualt in While loop for each loop

Comment: again, what is the **exact** content of `second.R`?

Comment: I have updated my post, I want to have  `position` and `datdb[position,2]` as result in First.R

Comment: You can only have one return value, so to speak. So change the end of `second.R` to `c(position, datdb[position,2])`, and then access them from `first.R` as `run1[1]` and `run1[2]`

Comment: If I do that I get this error: `Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Sheet index (-1) is out of range (0..2)`

Comment: @Kaja java?? what the hell does java have to do here?